# Expose filter with collabsible div on click in a Calendar

Tags: datetime

I have created a calendar showing Events in different cities.The City names are taken as Taxonomy and are displayed as a filter.On selecting a Particular city the Calendar shows all the events of that particular city in that month.I want the number of events in that particular city in the filter next to the city name.On clicking the City name in filter it should display the event details under it. Eg.If Atlanta have 4 events and Chicago have 1 event London doesnt have any event in July it should be displayed as

- Atlanta(4)
- Chicago(1)
- London(0)

for that particular month. On clicking the City the display is like-

Atlanta

- Event1
- Event2
- Event3

Chicago(2)

London(0)

ALong with calendar filtering and showing only Events related to Atlanta.

How to get this Functionality please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that each event is a node in Drupal, yes?

The filters you are describing are called 'facets', and there are a number of ways you can get them, but probably the most robust is to:

- Install [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) on your server if you haven't already
- Install the [Solr Search module](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) in Drupal and configure it to search your events
- Install the [Facets API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi) module and enable facets for your Country attribute

All of these things are well documented.

The one I had the most trouble with was the initial install of Apache Solr, but the instructions are specific to your O/S so unless you're using RedHat or a derivative, the [blog post that helped me](http://www.erikwebb.net/blog/installing-apache-solr-jetty-rhel-6/) won't be very useful.

Comment: I tried but finally I ended up in block template overriding.Thanks.